# Convert tz-aware pandas time series in pyarrow-backed df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pyarrow

I'm starting to play with pandas 2.0.0 and the pyarrow backend, I was trying to convert a processing function that I have (it reads data from a database and does some processing on it) by simply adding `dtype_backend="pyarrow"` as an argument for `pd.read_sql` as explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#argument-dtype-backend-to-return-pyarrow-backed-or-numpy-backed-nullable-dtypes).

The timestamp column (which is loaded as UTC by the query) looks like this:

```
0    2022-08-01 06:00:00+00:00
1    2022-08-01 07:00:00+00:00
2    2022-08-01 08:00:00+00:00
3    2022-08-01 09:00:00+00:00
4    2022-08-01 10:00:00+00:00
5    2022-08-01 11:00:00+00:00
6    2022-08-01 12:00:00+00:00
7    2022-08-01 13:00:00+00:00
8    2022-08-01 14:00:00+00:00
9    2022-08-01 15:00:00+00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: timestamp[ns, tz=UTC][pyarrow]
```

When it comes to converting the tz-aware timestamp column to a new tz as you can do normally with the numpy backend (`df["timestamp"] = df.timestamp.dt.tz_convert("Europe/Rome")`) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ArrowTemporalProperties' object has no attribute 'tz_convert'
```

If you look at the output of `dir(df.timestamp.dt)` you get a list that includes `'to_pydatetime'`, `'tz'` and `'tz_localize'` but no `tz_convert`.

Is this method not implemented for the pyarrow backend? Are there other options for converting tz-aware pyarrow timestamp series to some other tz?

EDIT: Turns out there is an [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51718) for this problem on the pandas github and an [open PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/52503) that addresses this and may be merged soon.

EDIT 2: The PR has been merged.